# Corrupted output when resizing with scale_npp filter ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I'm trying to transcode a single video file into multiple variants with different
resolutions/bitrates using GPU acceleration - in one command.

The encoding/decoding part is working great and produces results as expected.

**Main issue**

However when I try to resize using the **scale_npp** filter things start to turn green.
The resulting output from ffmpeg is just a green image

Similar to [Issue1](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2018-January/038435.html),
 [Issue2](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2018-January/038479.html) Already asked in ffmpeg forum but there is no answer for this issue

**Command i am using for conversion**

```
ffmpeg -y -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i input.mp4 -vf scale_npp=1280:720 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 360k -hls_time 10 -hls_segment_filename  output/ts_%03d.ts output/m3.m3u8
```

**My output video showing like** 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbVfV.jpg

I appreciate your help.
Thanks